# How to load example in Djinn/UU/Examples/Equality.hs?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

After `cabal install Djinn` which is using QuickCheck, the executable file is in `./.cabal/bin/djinn`.

then I copy the executable to the directory `Downloads/Djinn/UU/Examples/`

want to run example `Equality.hs` then `djinn Equality.hs`, can not parse command

then `./djinn` then `:load full path/UU/Examples/Equality.hs`

return cannot parse command

Comment: What's in `Equality.hs`?  I can't find it in [djinn's source repository](http://www.augustsson.net/Darcs/Djinn/).  Also, `djinn` is not supposed to work on Haskell source, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, this doesn't make much sense. Djinn doesn't work on Haskell source files as far as I know. Also Djinn doesn't appear to use quickcheck.